# array permutation with respect to some templates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, recursion

I have a template :on the basis of the templates i want permutation of array that are the part of the template and insert into db every one element of permutation data
Acutually the value of the template is dynamically change and the number of elements also varied means dynamic

```
  $temp = ['server', 'test[server]', 'extra'];
  $temp1 = ['server', 'test[server]'];
  $temp2 = ['server'];
```

test[server] -: test depends on server;
Data belongs to template:

```
  $server = ['server1','server2','server3'];
  $test = ['server1'=>['test1', 'test2'], 
           'server2' => ['test4', 'test5'], 
            'server3' => ['test7']];
   $extra = ['a','b','c'];
```

I want permutaion like :

FOR template $temp

```
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test1','extra'=>'a']
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test1','extra'=>'b']
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test1','extra'=>'c']
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test1','extra'=>'a']
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test2','extra'=>'a']
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test2','extra'=>'b']
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test2','extra'=>'c']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test4','extra'=>'a']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test4','extra'=>'b']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test4','extra'=>'c']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test5','extra'=>'a']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test5','extra'=>'b']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test5','extra'=>'c']
     ['server'=>'server3', 'test' => 'test7','extra'=>'a']
     ['server'=>'server3', 'test' => 'test7','extra'=>'b']
     ['server'=>'server3', 'test' => 'test7','extra'=>'c']
```

FOR template $temp1:

```
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test1']
     ['server'=>'server1', 'test' => 'test2']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test4']
     ['server'=>'server2', 'test' => 'test5']
     ['server'=>'server3', 'test' => 'test7']
```

FOR template $temp2:

```
     ['server'=>'server1']
     ['server'=>'server2']
     ['server'=>'server3']
```

after every one of permutaion element i want to insert in database:
         insert into table (server,test,extra)values(1 element each not all 
          I have memory issue because it has big array)

Answer (score 0):

So you need something like this? Of course, in your query change the table and field names. You can also access the `$newArray` array as you want.

```
$test = array('server1' => array('test1', 'test2'),
    'server2' => array('test4', 'test5'),
    'server3' => array('test7')
);
$extras = array('a', 'b', 'c');

$newArray = array();
foreach ($test as $server => $testArray) {
    foreach ($testArray as $test) {
        foreach ($extras as $extra) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra)"
                . " VALUES ('".$server."', '".$test."', '".$extra."')";
            echo $sql."<br />";
            $db->query($sql);
            $newArray[] = array("server" => $server, 'test' => $test, 'extra' => $extra);
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server1', 'test1', 'a')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server1', 'test1', 'b')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server1', 'test1', 'c')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server1', 'test2', 'a')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server1', 'test2', 'b')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server1', 'test2', 'c')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server2', 'test4', 'a')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server2', 'test4', 'b')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server2', 'test4', 'c')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server2', 'test5', 'a')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server2', 'test5', 'b')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server2', 'test5', 'c')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server3', 'test7', 'a')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server3', 'test7', 'b')
INSERT INTO tbl (server, test, extra) VALUES ('server3', 'test7', 'c')
```

Comment: it not the correct answer as i mention the length of template is not fixed and its element are varried

Comment: And? I am using `foreach` so you can add / remove elements... If you change the array, and for example, add a `d` to your extras, see what happens there. The array will be bigger.

Comment: the template might change as example $trmp = ['a','b','c[a]']

Comment: and how the server and test[server] related each other?

Comment: name is changing and data also change according to name so it is not a fixed name/value/length of every element.if the name value of template and corresponding array value change how we can handle --may be use of recursion but how

Comment: Now I've got it what you sad, just don't understand the server parts of it. I mean, I think if I ma change the `$temp` to `['other', 'thing']`, then I need to create 2 loops. All the `other`, and under every `other` all the `thing`, and so on. What i do not understand, how `$server`, and `$test['server']` related to each other. It's seams to me, there is a missing part from permutation.